# How to transpile es2015 to nodejs

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Since version 4.* of nodejs, is supports some features of ES2015, but not all. I want write app using ES2015 and transpile only features that doesn't support node.js

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is. There are transpilers which let you specify which features you want to transforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io) and configure it to only transform the relevant features. Assuming you're using  Babel 6 you would end up with a `.babelrc` file that looks something like this (assuming the only thing you want to transpile are template literals):

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-template-literals"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Better yet for this case (since Node supports many ES6 features), you can use the `blacklist` option to only exclude certain transforms.

Comment: @Harangue: Babel 6 doesn't have that option anymore I believe.

Comment: There are also some presets specifically for Node, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015-node .

Comment: @FelixKling - Good find, thanks! You are correct that Babel 6 no longer has the `blacklist` option.